# Django - relation "app_name_modelname" does not exist

Tags: django, digital-ocean, django-postgresql, django-deployment

I've deployed my application to DigitalOcean. Everything works fine except this situation. I've added new `GeneralComplaintDocument` model, made migration locally, pulled from Github last version of project on DigitalOcean's server, deleted all migration files, migrated again, but still getting this error:

```
relation "documents_app_generalcomplaintdocument" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "documents_app_generalcomplaintdocument"
```

models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    added_by = CurrentUserField()


class GeneralComplaintDocument(Document):
    complaint_reason = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.complaint_reason
```

P.S: everything works fine on local server.

Comment: why did you deleted all migration files ? Did you run `./manage.py migrate` on your Digital Ocean server ?

Comment: please add your model

Comment: @Charlesthk, yes I did...

Comment: @RiyasAc, ready

Comment: Ok and why did you deleted all migration files ?

Comment: @Charlesthk, because I've tried everything, and nothing helped. That was my last chance.

Comment: `django_migrations`  table remove all migration data where name is `documents_app` and then migrate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for do something like this:
first delete all migrations files in your app(`documents_app`)and next execute the below SQL query in your Database. Here we assume your app_name is `documents_app`.

```
delete FROM "django_migrations" WHERE "app" = 'documents_app';
```

then migrate ,

```
python manage.py makemigrations documents_app
python manage.py migrate documents_app
```

Comment: I've found error. In my database there is no 'GeneralComplaintDocument' table. I don't know why it is not adding after migrations...

Comment: The problem is you delete exisiting table.